# Wicket TextField with default value

Tags: java, wicket

What is an elegant way to create a TextField in wicket which is rendered with a default value besides manually setting the "value" attribute of the component using SimpleAttributeModifier?

For instance, this works:

```
TextField<String> headline = new TextField<String>("headline", new PropertyModel(backingObject, "headline"));
headline.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("value", "default value"));
add(headline);
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PropertyModel` works both ways. Instead of using the attribute modifier, just change the headline like so:

```
backingObject.setHeadline("[desired initial text]");
```

You can do this anywhere, it doesn't have to be after the `TextField` declaration. Of course, if you don't want to touch `backingObject` beforehand, this won't work, but I'm going to assume that's not an issue since you didn't mention it.

Comment: Thanks, finally found someone at work who gave me the same answer a couple hours ago. Great.